# Build.gradle compile work but I see this error

Tags: flutter, gradle, build, build.gradle

> Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle
> installation
> '/Users/davideresigotti/.sdkman/candidates/gradle/current'.
> org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred
> configuring root project 'android'. A problem occurred configuring
> root project 'android'. Could not resolve all files for configuration
> ':classpath'. Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.1.
> Required by:
> project : No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.1 was found. The consumer was
> configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with
> Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally,
> as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.3'
> but:
>
> - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.1 declares a library, packaged as a
>   jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
>
>   - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer
>     needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
>   - Other compatible attribute:
>
>     - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.3')
> - Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.1 declares a component for use
>   during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
>
>   - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
>   - Other compatible attributes:
>
>     - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
>     - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
>     - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.3')
> - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.1 declares a library for use during
>   runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
>
>   - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component,
>     compatible with Java 8
>   - Other compatible attribute:
>
>     - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.3')
> - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.1 declares a component for use
>   during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
>
>   - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
>   - Other compatible attributes:
>
>     - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
>     - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
>     - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.3')

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
// START: FlutterFire Configuration
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
// END: FlutterFire Configuration
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    namespace "com.example.soliveri_app"
    compileSdk 34


    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '17'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.soliveri_app"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

I tried everything, all don't work.

Comment: Please highlight the journal instead of publishing it as text. Read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

i encountered something similar but the reason behind that i didn't have AndroidStudio running as root to access or modify project files.

Running Android Studio and opening the App from using sudo solves it!

assume that you use macOS so consider these 2 commands :

```
   cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/
```

and then

```
   sudo ./studio
```

Comment: I don't have the problem on android studio but in vs code, and yes I'm on macOS

Comment: Have you tried opening the Android file project as if it's Native android app in AndroidStudio ?

Comment: in Android studio I don't see the error, I only see it in the problem view of vscode